# How do 'android:foreground' and 'android:foregroundGravity' in FrameLayout affect its appearance?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

FrameLayout has the attributes `android:foreground`, `android:foregroundGravity` and `android:measureAllChildren`.
I have tried these attributes, but couldn't make out how they affect the layout's appearance or how they work.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:foreground="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
 android:foregroundGravity="center"
 android:measureAllChildren="true"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.example.framelayoutdemo.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I have googled, but couldn't find a help with these attributes.
Please provide me a link which I can refer or help me with an example.
Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`android:foreground` points to the foreground that your `Framelayout` needs to draw on top of all its children

`android:foregroundGravity` points to the gravity of that asset, if that asset is a drawable. That means if you are using

```
android:foreground="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
```

Then your drawable is drawn on top of all its children and it is positioned in the center of the `Framelayout`

`android:measureAllChildren :` Determines whether to measure all children or just those in the `VISIBLE` or `INVISIBLE` state when measuring. Defaults to false. That means, if it is set to false, then all the elements in the `GONE` state are not taken into consideration when the `Framelayout`'s measure phase is going around.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Explanation for  `android:foreground` and `android:foregroundGravity` is perfect, but I didnt get how to use `android:measureAllChildren :`, or why to use. It will be a great help if you can provide and example for its working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `android:measureAllChildren` definitely has no effect on this layout.

Comment: @j__m I think `android:measureAllChildren` is used only for `ViewAnimator` and `ViewSwitcher`

Answer (score 3):

If measureallchildren is set to "true" then it will show actual width and height of the frame layout even if the views visibility is in gone state.
For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/myframe"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:measureAllChildren="true"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Below is the code of MainActivity.java . if we use Toast to display height and width on screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myframe_activity);
        FrameLayout frame=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame);
        frame.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int width = frame.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = frame.getMeasuredHeight();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"width="+width+"  height="+height,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

if we run the App in the Emulator the output in the form of Toast message will be like this:
width=72 height=72

Now if we change the value of measureAllChildren to false then Toast message output frame layout width and height will be:
width=0 height=0